# Deliver a 40kHz & >40V cosine wave to a transducer for communication

Tags: amplifier, ultrasound

I'm trying to do on/off keying (OOK) to transmit messages with ultrasound.

This is the [transducer.](https://www.ekulit.de/wp-content/uploads/datasheets/700620%20A-18P20.pdf)

This is the schematic of the signal generator and amplifier:

[image: Schematic of the signal gen and amp]

It seems that the class A amplifier doesn't work.

- Have I made an error with the operating point?
- Should I instead use opamps?

If you know how to fix this approach or if you have any better ideas please let me know.

Comment: I think you'll need to actively drive it "push-pull" and your example CE amplifier won't do that. I think that's one problem among several.

Comment: "Doesn't work" how?  No output?  Distorted output?  Output level too low?  It gets up off the work bench and kicks your cat?  What did you expect, and what did you get?  How did you check the output?  How do you know that the driving signal is OK?

Comment: Haben Sie auch ein englisches Datenblatt?

Comment: Mmmpf.  You won't get 40V output from a class A amplifier with a 5V supply.

Comment: @JRE sorry, the output atm is just a constant voltage but it should be like the square wave from the 555 just amplified

Comment: You can edit those into your question.  Comments get deleted sometimes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are going to use a class A amplifier on such a low voltage supply then might I suggest you configure the collector to drive a step up transformer. You can arbitrarily deliver what ever voltage you need to the secondary (within reason) but you might need some heat sinking on the output transistor.

The next problem is delivering a sine wave to the load. At the moment, the 555 produces a square wave and that’s roughly what you’d get in your current circuit (with or without an output transformer) so, you might be advised to use an op-amp low pass filter between 555 and the amplifier. You could use a pi network filter of course if you knew how to design it.

It’s unclear about how you would intend to perform OOK in the circuit but I would think that some logic input to the 555 and another transistor could be persuaded to give this functionality.

Comment: Yes, the OOK part is not included in the shematic because I wanted to focus this question on the carrier frequency gen and amp.

Comment: Yes, later I will attach RC or Pi Filter inbetween the 555 and the amp.

Comment: What do you think about just an emitter circuit and a 1:10 transformer (like this https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/597/ga3459-463457.pdf) after it ?

Comment: @le_lemon have you worked out what peak primary current would flow based on your load current expectations and whether this exceeds the value stated in the data sheet. You should use a common_emitter circuit in case what you said (*an emitter circuit*) was meant to be an emitter follower.

Comment: @Andy aka: That got lost in translation. German *Emitterschaltung* means the emitter is tied, so it's the same as English *common emitter circuit*.

Comment: I meant a common emitter circuit, thanks @Janka

Comment: @Andyaka how do I know what current flows at which voltage with this transducer ? I cant  find it in the datasheet https://www.ekulit.de/wp-content/uploads/datasheets/700620%20A-18P20.pdf

Comment: It has a capacitance of 1800 pF. That has a reactance of 2210 ohms at 40 kHz.

Comment: Be also aware of how long it takes for the transducer to decay its amplitude to zero and how long it takes to acquire full amplitude - this will determine how fast you can run your on-off keying data.

Comment: So I can just say the nominal current is 50V/2,2kOhm=22,5mA and the max is 170V/2,2kOhm=76,9mA ? Doesn't the capacitance change with the sound it receives ? At least thats what i've read in this paper https://download.atlantis-press.com/article/125906902.pdf

Comment: You mentioned 40 volts in your title - what is the | peak | voltage you want on your transducer? I'm not going to read that document in its entirety. Provide a verbatim quote I can search for.

Comment: @Andyaka 40V is the minimum peak to peak voltage needed for the transducer, it reaches the greates SPL above 100V but has a limit of 170V.  Verbatim: This is a model for piezoelectric transducers https://imgur.com/a/Oy1Yn7X In this shematic c0 is a static capacitance and the rest changes due to piezoelectric effects.

Comment: @le_lemon you asked me "Doesn't the capacitance change with the sound it receives" and I can't answer that without reading the whole document so, where you say that it does indicate this, please provide a quote verbatim so I can search for that text in the document you linked. The RMS current will be 14.14 volts ÷ 2200 Ω = 6.43 mA or a peak of 9.1 mA.

Comment: The document focuses on how to measure this model parameters but not on why the model is like it is. So I cant give you a quote. Thank you :)

Comment: @le_lemon just look back at what you said a few comments earlier: *Doesn't the capacitance change with the sound it receives ? At least that's what i've read in this paper* - in other words, how can I help you find an answer if you can't remember what you said?

Comment: Not sure if this is just a translation error so I am gonna try again. It was a stupid question in retrospective. Heres your verbatim quote: "The detection of the ultrasonic probe mainly includes four parts: static capacitance, resonance
frequency, residual vibration time and sensitivity. The ultrasonic probe can be equivalent to an RLC
series-parallel circuit [6], as shown in Fig. 1 (https://imgur.com/a/Oy1Yn7X)
Where C0 is the static capacitance, L1 is the equivalent inductance, C1 is the equivalent capacitance,
and R1 is the equivalent resistance."

Comment: And from that I deduced that L1 C1 and R1 change depending on the incoming sound. But that is nowhere explicitly said so in the text as far as I can tell.

Comment: Well, it behaves the same as a crystal so I doubt very much that capacitance will change with signal. It might shift a tad with temperature of course but I don't think you need worry about that in your application.

Comment: Yes ! The project just changed so much since and isn't finished yet so I didn't think about closing this question :D sorry

Answer (score 4):

Your DC blocking capacitor forms a high pass filter in combination with the input impedance of the amplifier.

The input impedance is less than 100 ohms, giving a cutoff of over 200kHz.

Your DC blocker is filtering out your ultrasound signal.

---

Other problems:

1. A simple class A amplifier can't put out a voltage higher than its supply voltage.  You have 5V in, so 40V out is not possible with this design.
2. The amplifier presents a heavy load to the 555.  The 555 may have trouble delivering enough current to the BD139 base.
3. You've already mentioned that you know that your signal is a square wave and that you'll have to filter it to make a sine wave out of it.  Keep the low input impedance of your amplifier in mind when you design the filter.  You might do better to useva buffer between the filter output and the amplifier input.

Comment: How would you solve those problems: should I increase the dc block capacitance ? Would you exchange the class a amplifier for something else ? I could attach a emitter circuit inbetween the 555 and the amp to lower the amount of current the 555 needs to deliver.

Comment: The DC block capacitor needs to be larger.  Say, 100nF or more.  An emitter follower would be one way to improve things, but I think you're going to want to use a different type of amplifier as Andy aka says.  That also changes the DC blocking and what kind of buffer you might need.  A class A amplifier wastes over 75% of the consumed power - it gets hot.

Answer (score 3):

Ultrasound transducers require only very small currents. Instead of using an audio transformer, you might want to try a CMOS H-Bridge running at 15V. The H configuration gives you 30Vss accross the transducer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feqKHw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I just use 3 common emitter circuits because those act as inverters; on one side of the transducerr 1 and on the other 2 so I get for example -5V on one side and +5V on the other so that in total i get a Vss of 10V across. Like this: https://imgur.com/SPiuEsZ

Comment: In falstad this leads to a switching between -5V and +5V but not to 10V http://tinyurl.com/y4ra9whd. What did I do wrong ?

Comment: @le_lemon: Switching between -5V and +5V is 10V peak to peak. The transducer spec sheet lists peak-to-peak voltage.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Thanks! Im gonna build this on monday and tell you how it went :)

Comment: No, my idea was to use a CD4049 inverter chip and run it at 15–18V supply voltage. That's within its spec. (They burn out at roughly 20V, so don't try that.)

Comment: I cant find a inverter chip for higher voltage tough. +/-50V would be ideal. What do you think about this approach with CMOS inverters ? https://imgur.com/a/6hOqydH

Comment: For more than +-18V, you need a different approach.